# ES6 Destructing for objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I am new to ES6 destructing. I have an object which contains another object. I want to store certain values from the nested object.

For example -

```
z = {g: 1, h: 2, i: {d1:5, d2:6, d3:7}}
```

When I do

```
let { g, i : {d1, d3}, ...less } = z
```

the `less` variable only stores `h` and not `d2`.

Is there a way to make it so it is

```
less = {h, i : {d2}}
```

Comment: You could do `let { g, i : {d1, d3, ...less1}, ...less2 } = z; let result = {...less1, ...less2}`, though I'm not sure what the "boundaries" of your request are.

Comment: There is no simple approach for it (I believe), but in that particular example you can do: `let { g, i : {d1, d3, ...i_less}, ...less } = z; less = {...less, i: {...i_less}};`

Answer (score 0):

No there is not. What you could do is

```
let { g, i: { d1, d3, ...less2 }, ...less } = z
let less = { ...less, i: less2 };
```

This extracts the remainder and merges them back together while preserving the shape.

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately this is not possible.
You can however extract the missing values from i with a second rest spread:

```js
let z = {g: 1, h: 2, i: {d1:5, d2:6, d3:7}};
let { g, i : {d1, d3, ...i_less}, ...rest_less } = z;
let less = { i: i_less, ...rest_less };
console.log(less)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my way, hope it could help.

```js
let z = {
  g: 1,
  h: 2,
  i: {
    d1:5,
    d2:6,
    d3:7
  }
}

let {g, i: {d1, d3, ...less1}, ...less2} = z
let less = {
  i: less1,
  ...less2,
}

console.log(less); // output: {h: 2, i:{d2:6}}
```